# Collision resistance

Tags: collision-resistance

I have function with input 128 bit and output 64 bit that hash the header and hash the payload then  concatenating them after that hash the result so my question is does this pass the collision security requirement? or it fail because the attacker can find the hash 2^32?

Comment: Is it possible that you are [Wei-Xia](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/76119/wei-xia?tab=questions) or friend of they? [How can we justify if a Hash function is preimage resistance, second resistance and collision resistance?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77269/18298)

Comment: look under related questions that appear on the right column to your question, as well. This is not a new question. And you haven't even bothered to state it mathematically.